# How should I be writing to STDOUT from Node with readline in the mix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, stdin, pipeline

I have a Javascript file being executed by Nodejs as a script in a Unix shell pipeline. The script needs to read (a few thousand lines) of text from STDIN, parse it for some bits, then return a json stream on STDOUT with the results of its work.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});
```

Then I have some functions to process the data, then I setup an event listener that gets called on each line of input and does all the processing I need and appends it to an array:

```
function extract_references (data) {
  ...
  references.push(item);
}
rl.on('line', extract_references);
```

So far so good, my data array ends up populated with all the components I want. The trouble comes when I try to write it back out to STDOUT. I've tried a couple things being triggered by the close event on the input stream:

```
function output_references () {
  var output = JSON.stringify(references, null, '  ');
  process.stdout.write(output);
}
rl.on('close', output_references);
```

This works fine if the input stream is relatively short (a couple hundred lines) but when I crank it up to my full data set I start getting truncated output and an error such as:

> write error: Resource temporarily unavailable

...from the next command in my pipeline.

I've also tried using `rl.write()`, but that doesn't seem to give me anything at all on STDOUT. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to handle a stream like this?